# How to call predicate method in controller of rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I am new to rails and am trying to get the following bit of rspec to pass that will enable calling a path to flag a course as hidden:

```
describe 'PATCH hide_course' do
    before :each do
        @course = create(:course)
    end

    it 'marks the course as hidden' do
        patch :hide_course, id: @course
        expect(@course.reload.hidden?).to be_true
    end

    it 'redirects to courses#index' do
        patch :hide_course, id: @course
        expect(response).to redirect_to course_url
    end
end
```

I then set the following route with no problems:

```
resources :courses
put '/courses/:id/hide_course', to: 'courses#hide_course'
```

My problem is in setting the controller action. Here is the bit I wrote in my CoursesController:

```
def hide_course
    @course = Course.find(params[:id])
    @course.hide
end

private

def course_params
    params.require(:course).permit(:name,:description,:department,:hidden,
        :lecture_attributes => [:name,:description,:level])
end
```

My model then looks like this:

```
def hide
    update!(:hidden => true)
end
```

What is the best way for me to set up this method in rails 4? I keep getting errors about the hidden attribute not existing even though it is in my schema. Thanks!

PS- The backtrace I get for the first spec is this:

```
 1) CoursesController PATCH hide_course marks the course as hidden
     Failure/Error: patch :hide_course, id: @course
     ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError:
       unknown attribute: hidden
     # /Users/sjensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:59:in `rescue in _assign_attribute'
     # /Users/sjensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:54:in `_assign_attribute'
     # /Users/sjensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:41:in `block in assign_attributes'
     # /Users/sjensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:35:in `each'
     # /Users/sjensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:35:in `assign_attributes'
     # /Users/sjensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:262:in `block in update!'
     # /Users/sjensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:345:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
     # /Users/sjensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
     # /Users/sjensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:188:in `within_new_transaction'
     # /Users/sjensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
     # /Users/sjensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:218:in `transaction'
     # /Users/sjensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:342:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
     # /Users/sjensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:261:in `update!'
     # ./app/models/course.rb:13:in `hide'
     # ./app/controllers/courses_controller.rb:60:in `hide_course'
     # /Users/sjensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.2.0.beta2/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
     # /Users/sjensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.2.0.beta2/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
     # /Users/sjensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.2.0.beta2/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
     # /Users/sjensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.2.0.beta2/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
     # /Users/sjensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:114:in `call'
     # /Users/sjensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:114:in `call'
     # /Users/sjensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:231:in `block in halting'
     # /Users/sjensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:231:in `call'
     # /Users/sjensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:231:in `block in halting'
     # /Users/sjensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
     # /Users/sjensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
     # /Users/sjensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
     # /Users/sjensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
     # /Users/sjensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:231:in `call'
     # /Users/sjensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:231:in `block in halting'
     # /Users/sjensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
     # /Users/sjensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
     # /Users/sjensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:87:in `call'
     # /Users/sjensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:87:in `run_callbacks'
     # /Users/sjensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.2.0.beta2/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
     # /Users/sjensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.2.0.beta2/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
     # /Users/sjensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.2.0.beta2/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
     # /Users/sjensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
     # /Users/sjensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
     # /Users/sjensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
     # /Users/sjensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.2.0.beta2/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
     # /Users/sjensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.2.0.beta2/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
     # /Users/sjensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
     # /Users/sjensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.2.0.beta2/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
     # /Users/sjensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionview-4.2.0.beta2/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
     # /Users/sjensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.2.0.beta2/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:628:in `process'
     # /Users/sjensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.2.0.beta2/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:64:in `process'
     # /Users/sjensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.2.0.beta2/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:516:in `patch'
     # ./spec/controllers/courses_controller_spec.rb:171:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: Why `?` mark in your attribute `hidden?`. I can see your attribute name is `hidden`.

Comment: Good question, I was going off an example in the book: Everyday Rails Testing with Rspec. It seems to give me the unknown attribute error even when I remove the ?

Comment: the `?` in flag/boolean attributes is a convention to denote the attribute is a flag, and to give some syntax sugar for `if`s and `unless`

Comment: can you paste the error backtrace?

Comment: Thanks rafb3, I added the backtrace.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your test db is setup correctly. Try running `rake db:test:prepare`

Comment: I am running rails 4.2 which manages the test database automatically, I believe (at least that is the warning I get when I run that command). I have been using rspec to code the usual model specs with no problems in this project so I think the test db is okay.  Thanks!